# Vertically align separation line between title and subtitle

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I am desperately trying to (1) vertically align title and subtitle of a titlepage whilst (2) creating a separation line exactly between title and subtitle. This is what I've got so far:
[image]

The vertical space of the separation line is obviously way too huge. But if I try to fiddle around with `\vskip` or `\vfill`, the line is not vertically centered between the title and subtitle anymore. This picture shows the right spacing between title and separation line (the spacing between separation line and subtitle is obviously off):

[image]

I'm also struggling to have the separation line as long as the actual width of the title. But that's just a minor problem.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[leqno,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%%% Fußzeile: deutsches Datum, Autor:in, Folienzahl %%%
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{date}%
           \vspace{2.5pt}
            \usebeamerfont{date}\hspace*{3ex}
            \insertshortdate{}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author}%
           \vspace{2.5pt} \usebeamerfont{author}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{pageno}%
            \vspace{2.5pt} 
            \usebeamerfont{pageno}
            \insertframenumber{}\hspace*{7ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother

%%% Titelfolie %%%
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    \centering  % <-- Center here
\vfill%
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
    \vfill%
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi\\
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.5pt,wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}  \vfill%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi \vfill%
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \vfill
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title}{
%  \raggedright%  % <-- Comment here
  \Huge\rmfamily\scshape{\inserttitle}%
  \par%
\
  \vspace*{0.5em}
}
\setbeamertemplate{subtitle}{
%  \raggedright%  % <-- Comment here
  \huge\rmfamily\scshape\insertsubtitle%
  \par%
  \vspace*{0.5em}
}
\makeatother



\author{Vitus Schäfftlein}
\title{This is quite a long and completely useless title}
\subtitle{And this is quite a long and completely useless subtitle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Anyone out there who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the space symmetrically by choosing the same value in the two lines I marked with `% here`:

```
\documentclass[leqno,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%%% Fußzeile: deutsches Datum, Autor:in, Folienzahl %%%
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{date}%
           \vspace{2.5pt}
            \usebeamerfont{date}\hspace*{3ex}
            \insertshortdate{}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author}%
           \vspace{2.5pt} \usebeamerfont{author}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}

        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{pageno}%
            \vspace{2.5pt} 
            \usebeamerfont{pageno}
            \insertframenumber{}\hspace*{7ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother

%%% Titelfolie %%%
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    \centering  % <-- Center here
\vfill%
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
    \vfill%
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi\\
    \vspace{0.25cm} % here
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.5pt,wd=\textwidth]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}  
%    \vfill%
    \vspace*{0.25em} % here
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi \vfill%
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \vfill
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title}{
%  \raggedright%  % <-- Comment here
  \Huge\rmfamily\scshape{\inserttitle}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subtitle}{
%  \raggedright%  % <-- Comment here
  \huge\rmfamily\scshape\insertsubtitle%
  \par%
  \vspace*{0.5em}
}
\makeatother



\author{Vitus Schäfftlein}
\title{This is quite a long and completely useless title}
\subtitle{And this is quite a long and completely useless subtitle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```